# How to apply a function in different ranges of a vectror in R?

Tags: r, matrix, max, element

I have the following matrix:

```
x=matrix(c(1,2,2,1,10,10,20,21,30,31,40,
           1,3,2,3,10,11,20,20,32,31,40,
           0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0),11,3)
```

I would like to find for each unique value of the first column in `x`, the maximum value (across all records having that value of the first column in `x`) of the third column in `x`.

I have created the following code:

```
v1 <- sequence(rle(x[,1])$lengths)
A=split(seq_along(v1), cumsum(v1==1))
A_diff=rep(0,length(split(seq_along(v1), cumsum(v1==1))))
for( i in 1:length(split(seq_along(v1), cumsum(v1==1))) )
{
A_diff[i]=max(x[split(seq_along(v1), cumsum(v1==1))[[i]],3])
}
```

However, the provided code works only when same elements are consecutive in the first column (because I use `rle`) and I use a `for` loop.

So, how can I do it to work generally without the `for` loop as well, that is using a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly

```
> tapply(x[,3],x[,1],max)

 1  2 10 20 21 30 31 40 
 1  1  1  0  1  1  0  0
```

For grouping more than 1 variable I would do aggregate, note that matrices are cumbersome for this purpose, I would suggest you transform it to a data frame, nonetheless

```
> aggregate(x[,3],list(x[,1],x[,2]),max)
```

Comment: How can I apply this function in both first and second columns of matrix `x`?